# SCRIPT5022: SCRIPT5022: Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationModule: (?)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, webpack

I am using Angular 7 and the latest version of web pack. 
Initialized Angular 7 through Angular CLI. When I tried using web pack with enabling production mode, I am getting the below error.

SCRIPT5022: SCRIPT5022: Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationModule: (?).

[image]

**Webpack.config.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.ts',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: ['ts-loader', 'angular2-template-loader'],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(html|css)$/,
        loader: 'raw-loader'
      },
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app/'),
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html',
      inject: 'body'
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      // global app config object
      config: JSON.stringify({
        apiUrl: 'http://localhost:4000'
      })
    })
  ],
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
    },
    runtimeChunk: true
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
};
```

**main.ts**

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import './polyfills';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

console.log(environment.production);

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

**polyfill.js**

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "app/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hi, have you find solution to solve your issue ?